# Google line chart highlight

Tags: graph, linechart

I am passing 4 columns to create a line chart, out of which i don't want to highlight the 4th column.
I have disabled the selection event for the 4th column and at the same time i don't want to highlight the 4th column.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'highlight'? What do you expect to (not)happen? And could you show your code: how you disabled the selection event?

Comment: I mean highlight on mouseover.